# Generate a number different from the numbers in the array

Tags: algorithm

There is an array (greater than 1000 elements space) with 1000 large numbers (can be 64 bit numbers as well). The numbers in the array may not be necessarily sorted.
We have to generate a unique number at 1001th position that is different from the previous 1000. 
Justify the approach used is the best.

My answer (don't know to what extent this was correct):
Sort the numbers, and start from the 0 position. The number that is at 1000th position + 1 is the required number.

Better suggestions for this?

Comment: What does "unique" mean? just different from the others? Or should be different for each set of numbers? Should it be random (If it does - the suggested solution fails)? Also note: no need in sorting in your solution, just find the max - it is more efficient. Your solution also fails if the 1000th element is INT_MAX

Comment: `Unique` can be anything different from the previous 1000. Also, this will be a function to generate 1002th, 1003th numbers and so on.

Comment: Are you allowed to disturb the array? Are you allowed to use O(N) additional space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an auxiliary array of 1001 elements.  Set all these to 1 (or true or Y or whatever you choose).  Run through the main array, if you find a number in the range 1..1000 then 0 out (or falsify some other how) the corresponding element in the auxiliary array.  At the end the first element in the auxiliary array which is not 0 (or false) corresponds to a number which is not in the main array.

This is simple, and, I think, O(n) in time complexity, where n is the number of elements in the main array.

Comment: Nice approach. One drawback I see is for producing `k` elements (as OP mentions in comments) will be `O(n+k)` space. However - for small `k`: (something like `k < 64*n`) it seems more space-efficient because you only need one bit per element in the array.

Comment: @amit: you understand why I only mentioned the time complexity of this approach :-)

Comment: Nevertheless - it is a nice thinking out of the box approach. Also worth mentioning: correctness is fulfilled due to [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). +1

Comment: If OP wants more than one number, then use an auxiliary array of 1000+k numbers, where k>1.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned ii,slot;

unsigned array [ NNN ];
/* allocate a histogram */
#define XXX (NNN+1);
unsigned histogram [XXX];
memset(histogram, 0, sizeof histogram);

for (ii=0; ii < NNN; ii++) {
        slot = array [ii ] % XXX;
        histogram[slot] += 1;
        }
for (slot=0; slot < NNN; slot++) {
        if ( !histogram[slot]) break;
        }

/* Now, slot + k * XXX will be a 
** number that does not occur in the original array */
```

Note: this is similar to High performance Mark, but at least I typed in the code ...

Answer (score 0):

If you sort your array, you have three possibilities for a unique number:

1. array[999]+1, if array[999] is not equal to INT_MAX
2. array[0]-1, if array[0] is not equal to INT_MIN
3. a number between array[i] and array[i+1], if array[i+1]-array[i]>1 (0<=i<=998). Notice that if the two previous tries have failed, then it is guaranteed that there is a number between two elements in your array.

Notice that this solution will also work for the 1002th, 1003th, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt at a clumsy c# implementation

```
public class Test
{
    public List<int> Sequence { get; set; }

    public void GenerateFirstSequence()
    {
        Sequence = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var x = new Random().Next(0, int.MaxValue);
            while (Sequence.Contains(x))
            {
                x = new Random().Next(0, int.MaxValue);
            }
            Sequence.Add(x);
        }
    }

    public int GetNumberNotInSequence()
    {
        var number = Sequence.OrderBy(x => x).Max();
        var mustRedefine = number == int.MaxValue && Sequence.Contains(number);
        if (mustRedefine)
        {
            while (Sequence.Contains(number))
            {
                number = number - 1;
                if (!Sequence.Contains(number))
                    return number;
            }
        }
        return number + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some thoughts on this problem:

You could create a hash table H, which contain 1000 elements. Suppose your array named A, and for each element, we have the reminder by 1000: m[i] = A[i] % 1000.

If there is a conflict between A[i] and A[j], that A[i] % 1000 = A[j] % 1000. That is to say, there must exist an index k, that no element's reminder by 1000 equals to k, then k is the number you are going to get.

If there is no conflict at all, just pick H[1] + 1000 as your result.

The complexity of this algorithm is O(l), in which l indicates the original list size, in the example, l = 1000